# Referencing tags in resources with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, tagging, infrastructure-as-code

How can I reference a common set of tags in cloudFormation without declaring tags in each resource if possible?

For example, with Terraform you can create a `locals.tf` file and have a block for tags to be applied across your deployed resources `common_tags` . Example:

```
locals {
  common_tags = {
    project = "asigra_errors_processing"
    environment = "dev"
    author = "zimcanit"
    }
}
```

By referencing the tags with `tags = local.common_tags`, I could assign tags to an s3 bucket as shown below, with just one line of code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "asigra_s3" {
    bucket = "logged-asigra-errors-2022"
    region = var.aws_region
    tags = local.common_tags
}
```

Is it possible to do the above, but with CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using the cli and update-stack command with the --tags option to push tags written in a tags.json file stored locally to my cloudFormation stack in AWS.

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name infrastructure --template-body  file://<insert filepath to cloudformation template file here> --tags file://<insert filepath to json file containing tags to be propogated across deployed resources>
```

Reference AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html#update-stack